# Call method with bytes argument from Truffle

Tags: truffle, bytes

When calling a Smart Contract method that requires a bytes parameter, truffle is not accepting the bytes parameter, no matter how I express it. All these tests fail on truffle:

```
// 0x6154696d657374616d704576656e744369706865726564 is hex for string 'aTimestampEventCiphered'
let bytecode = myMethod(..., 0x6154696d657374616d704576656e744369706865726564).encodeABI();
let bytecode = myMethod(..., web3.fromUtf8("aTimestampEventCiphered")).encodeABI();
let bytecode = myMethod(..., "aTimestampEventCiphered").encodeABI();
let bytecode = myMethod(..., "0x6154696d657374616d704576656e744369706865726564").encodeABI();
let bytecode = myMethod(..., bytes("aTimestampEventCiphered")).encodeABI();
let bytecode = myMethod(..., web3.fromAscii("aTimestampEventCiphered")).encodeABI();
```

Truffle is throwing this error on and on:

```
Error: invalid bytes value (arg="_timestampEventCiphered", coderType="bytes", value=9.322336429922961e+54)
```

Any idea how to properly send a bytes argument from truffle? Thx!

Comment: If you're using Truffle 4.1.14 or earlier, which I know for sure to rely on web3 v0.x, then the last line should work.

Comment: If you're using a later version of Truffle, which has possibly switched to web3 v1.x (I sure as hell hope not, because that would yield a ton of changes in my testing infrastructure), then replace `web3.fromAscii` with `web3.utils.asciiToHex`.

Comment: I've used Truffle and it accepts strings in hexadecimal with 0x prefix as bytes array, like this `let bytecode = myMethod(..., "0x6154696d657374616d704576656e744369706865726564")` . Likely you have another error.

Comment: This "0x6154696d657374616d704576656e744369706865726564" is a string in itself and throws same error: invalid bytes value...

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPérezSacristán I've tried with both truffle v4 an v5 and both accept "0x11223344" as a bytes array. What is your solidity function like? and How are you making the call to the contract? I can execute from the console without issues `m.foo(web3.utils.toHex("hola"))` or `m.foo('0x686f6c6101')`. Javascript is quite lax on types types so it should not complain about string, perhaps are you using typescript or other language?